# Result of exec system call made by child process

Tags: c

I am new to C and was wondering what happens when the child process calls exec system call to execute a new program?

Comment: Did you even try to research your question before asking?

Comment: Welcome to So https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec()` family of functions **replaces** the `current process` with a `new process image` specified as its 1st argument.

```
int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
```

for e.g

```
main() {
        execl("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
}
```

When you will execute above code, your `current running process(a.out`) will be replaced by `new process` called **ls**.

You can use `fork()` and explore more.

```
main() {
        if(fork()==0){ /** child process is in sleep for 5 second**/
                sleep(5);
                exit(0);/** once job is done child need to send it's status to parent process using exit **/
        }
        else { /** parent process **/
                wait(0);/** parent waits upto child got done, then it replaces whole child child pcb with parent PCB **/
                execl("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
        }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

From the `exec` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html),

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image
>          with a new process image.

So, the child process is replaced with the exec'd process.